# Output of php function "strtotime()" is confused

Tags: php

I have no idea about output of this function.

" `strtotime(date("j"),date("F"),date("t"))` "

Output: 1475734243

That output is changing according to the time.

my code block is:

```
<?php
    $day= date("j");
    $month= date("F");
    $year=  date("Y");


    //calendar Variables
    $currentTimeStamp=  strtotime($day-$month-$year);

    echo $currentTimeStamp;

    ?>
```

date("j") gives Day of the month without leading zeros (1 to 31).
date("F") gives A full textual representation of a month, such as January or March.
date("Y") gives A full numeric representation of a year, 4 digits (eg: 2016).

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: So, what is the actual question? - And what part of the strtotime's docs was confusing?

Comment: strtotime convert your date format like "31-March-2016" to unix time (integer)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [strtotime documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php).

It returns the number of seconds passed since the U-day (January 1 1970 00:00:00 UTC) to the date (in string representation) that is provided as an argument. It's also called "Unix timestamp" and "Unix epoch (time)"

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure what part is confusing but if I got it right that you want to display the current date with that format then you should use this without having to use strtotime()

```
echo date("j F Y");
```

Sample working output:
https://repl.it/Dodz/0

Comment: This is even cleaner.

Answer (score 1):

The output is a unix time stamp.

`echo $day.'-'.$month.'-'.$year;`

`echo date('j-F-Y', strtotime($currentTimeStamp));`

This will give you the answer you are looking for.